# Drag drop open file in Macvim split window?

Tags: text-editor, vim, macvim

I like to use the split window feature in Vim. However I cannot seem to drag drop new files into the different sections.  Doing so will just open a new tab.  I don't like using tabs as I still need to flick between them and not much different to using separate windows.

Is there anyway I can change this behaviour? It works fine on Windows gVim and Im using the same vimrc file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation ([`:help macvim-drag`](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/source/browse/trunk/runtime/doc/gui_mac.txt?r=292#79)):

```
Dragging files and dropping them on a window opens those files in tabs in that
window, unless Vim is in command-line mode.  In command-line mode the names of
the files are added to the command line.  Holding down modifier keys whilst
dragging is not supported.

If a file is dropped on the Dock icon, it is always opened in a new tab
regardless of the mode Vim is currently in.  The same holds if you
double-click on a file in the Finder.

The "Open files from applications" preference in the General preference pane
gives more options on how dropped files should open, in case tabs are not
desired.
```